# Cross compile shared libraries

Tags: go, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'd like to know if it is possible (and if yes: how) to cross compile shared libraries with Go. Say I have this code:

```
package main

import "C"

//export DoubleIt
func DoubleIt(x int) int {
    return x * 2
}

func main() {}
```

in `src/doubler/main.go`. On Mac I can run

```
go build -o libdoubler.dylib -buildmode=c-shared doubler
```

to get a shared library called `libdoubler.dylib`. Similar on linux, just with the extension `.so`.

Now I'd like to use Linux as the main platform to build my libraries (for Mac and Windows). What are my options?

Setting `GOOS` to `darwin` and running the above on linux, I get

```
can't load package: package doubler: no buildable Go source files in /home/patrick/Desktop/go/src/doubler
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you face is not actually about compiling shared libraries or executables, but about using cgo and trying to cross-compile. (Still, if you want a library, not an executable, package name shouldn't be `main`.)

When cross-compiling, cgo is disabled by default. If you add the environment variable `CGO_ENABLED=1`, then your example will work:

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=darwin go build -o libdoubler.dylib -buildmode=c-shared doubler
```

Keep in mind that using cgo while cross-compiling will be cumbersome. You will need to make sure that C libraries for the target platform are ready on your host machine. If it is not really necessary, stay away from cgo. If you have to, then you may consider compiling on the target machine instead of dealing with the maintenance of cross-compiling with cgo.

Comment: To say, don't works on my machine. ld unrecognizes flags and gcc returns exit status 1

Comment: `package main` and `-buildmode=c-shared` won't work together. I assumed the OP was aware of it as another answer already stated that problem. I have edited my answer to clarify this point. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have always misspelled CGO_ENABLED... Now it "works" in a sense that it doesn't throw any errors anymore. I whish the solution would have been without installing a cross compilation environment.

Comment: @hasanyasin I have no problems with `package main` on OS X.

Comment: If package is main, we are cross-compiling with GOOS=darwin on a linux machine and we want it to produce a shared package, then linking fails as uvelichitel mentioned.

If you use pure go, then cross-compiling is a breeze. If you use non-Go libraries, then there is no way around having those libraries for the target platform. Can't play lego without lego bricks. :)

Comment: Somehow (Go 1.9, macOS 10.13) it only works when I have the package named `main`. Otherwise I get a `current ar archive` not `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

when building a client use :

```
package main
```

... however building a library use :

```
package mylibname
```