# How to build SO library for ARM architecture

Tags: go, arm, cgo, gccgo

I need to build a shared library in Go. For this purpose, I used `CGO` and then built `SO` lib with options

> go build -o libUtil.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go

Now, I need to do the same, but for `ARM` architecture. When I do not use `CGO`, I only do `export GOARCH=arm`
and this is enough to succeed. However, when I use `CGO`, I can not build `SO` library.

I suspect, that I need to install *arm build tools*, but I don`t know how to do that and how to configure my GO environment to use these tools. I hope, somebody might help me.

OS is Linux.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710987/cross-compile-shared-libraries

Answer (score 0):

It may be different in you own *.nix system, but in common case your settings shoul de like below:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc //choose your arm compiler binary
export GOARCH=arm
export CGO_ENABLED=1
```

then you cab build:

```
go build -o yourLib.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go
```